# data received from laravel controller not updating to vue variable

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, axios

I am creating a web app having dashboard using laravel and vue. 
When I pass data from controller to vue file data is received properly but when I set it to vue variable the value is not set in the variable. All data is received and its displayed in the console but when I set it to the vue variable, the variable doesn't update its value.
This is my Controller class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
class UsersController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function index()
    {
        $users=User::all();

        return response()->json($users);
    }
}
```

This is myTeam.vue for receiving and displaying the data:

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card card-default">
                    <div class="card-header">Example Component</div>


                    <h1>
                       This request list
                       Hello,{{this.items}}
                    </h1>

                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <li class="list-group-item" v-for="t in items">{{items}}</li>

                    </ul>

                      </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data(){
            return {
                 //items: []
                 items:[],

            }
        },

        created() {
            var self=this;
             axios.get('/allusers').then((response) => self.items=response.data) .catch((error)=>console.log(error));

             axios.get('/allusers') .then(response => console.log(response.data));

            console.log('Component mounted.'+this.items)
        },


    }
</script>
```

Now when I run it the console prints the array properly means data is received but when I set it to items variable the data is not set.

**My Output is this:**
[This is the output image file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjKR6.jpg)

Please check it and thanks in advance ...

Comment: have you tried {{this.items[0]}}? If it shows row [0], meaning it is not posible to show 2 or more row in the element.

Comment: you put `console.log('Component mounted.'+this.items)` inside callback since ajax is asynchronous or you may use promises

Comment: use as ``Hello,{{items}}`` no need to use `this` to access data attributes.

Comment: still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is never print items array because it's execute before the ajax response is filled.

```
    console.log('Component mounted.'+this.items)
```

That's why your console is always blank. You can search about [blocking and non blocking](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/blocking-vs-non-blocking/) programming.

your code have small bug. Update your code and try this:

```
<h1>
 This request list
    Hello,{{items}}
</h1>

<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item" v-for="t in items">{{t}}</li>
</ul>
...

<script>
    export default {
        data(){
            return {
                items:[],
            }
        },
        mounted: function () {
            this.getList();
        }

        methods: {
            let _this = this;
            axios.get('/allusers')
            .then((response) => _this.items = response.data) 
            .catch((error)=>console.log(error));
        },
    }
</script>
```

[This can](https://jsbin.com/benotuqane/edit?html,output) help you. Good luck.

Comment: I have tried it but still the variable is not updating with the received value. The problem is that the value is not updating in the vue variable

Comment: Thanks @Gautam Patadiya but still the same problem nothing in displayed as value is not updated. I have tried different ways of doing it but still vue variable is not updating. It happens when I update variable using axios . Is there any other way for doing such thing except axios. I dont know why updating from axios is causing issues

Comment: Thanks @Gautam Patadiya but still variable value not updating .

Comment: @Osama may be your screen from cache I create new jsbin with example and there code is working very well.

Comment: Thanks @Gautam Patadiya. The problem is solved. Your code for printing the values using ul was helpful. Another step that I did was to reinstall the axios using npm command . Both these steps solved my problem. Thanks. To reinstall axios see this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-axios